# I installed postgreSQL on Windows server and want to have access control for users. How do it integrate it with Active Directory?

Tags: windows, postgresql, active-directory

I installed postgreSQL on Windows server, created a database and want to have access control for users. How do it integrate it with Active Directory?
Most of the blogs i viewed were having postgres installed on Linux machine. I need the steps for AD integration for postgres installed on Windows machine.

Comment: See the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sspi-auth.html.   If you really prefer random blog posts, search for one with 'SSPI'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) for your valuable suggestion. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can use SSPI authentication to integrate PostgreSQL with Active directory.

> To configure SSPI authentication for PostgreSQL follow below steps:

- **Identify Administrative Account**

Identify you Administrative Account by using below PowerShell cmdlets

```
"$env:username"

"$env:username@$env:userdomain"
```

- **Log in to pgAdmin 4**

Lauch pgAdmin and enter the master password to connect to the server.

- **Create Administrative Account in Postgres**

*Expand Servers -> select PostgreSQL 11 -> right click on login/group roles -> select create -> Under general key -> In privileges check all to yes.*

- **Open File Explorer to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data**

Configure postgres to make use of it in SSPI mode and modify two files in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data

****Edit pg_ident.conf**** : In system-username if the value has space then enclose the value with double quotes and In PG-username , create the postgresql user if it is not available , username should be case sensitive
****Modify pg_hba.conf****: Edit "pg_hba.conf" modifying the appropriate existing line from md5 to sspi, mentioning the user map that we established in pg_ident.conf.

- **Reload Postgres Configuration**

In start menu, Search Reload configuration and launch as administrator.

- **Confirm SSPI**

*Shut down & restart Pgadmin -> Enter master password -> Expand servers -> cancel the login prompt -> Under servers -> right click on PostgreSQL 11 -> select properties -> connection tab -> **change postgres to your Windows user** -> Save*

For more in detail, please find below **links** if they are helpful

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sspi-auth.html

https://techdocs.ed-fi.org/display/TSINSTALL/Configuring+SSPI+Authentication+for+PostgreSQL